# How to find real height of panel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

If I set the size of a JPanel by using for instance the method setPreferedSize(new Dimension(0,160,10,10)) but then I add a lot of other components (for instance a series of big buttons) and the panel exceeds the size of 160px: how do I find the real height of panel ?

Comment: In most situations, you would not need to know.  Set an appropriate layout manager & let it do its job.

Answer (score 2):

Use `JComponent#getHeight()`. From its JavaDoc: `Returns the current height of this component.`

Comment: it will not work if we set size using setPrefferedSize(); only work if we have set size using setSize()

Comment: @Harry The layout manager will likey call `component.setBounds(...)` which in turn updates width and height. `setPreferredSize()` will just set the preferred size as a hint to the layout manager.

Comment: @Harry Before or after letting the layout manager do its job? Note that right after setting the preferred size, the current size is still 0, since it has not been set yet. If you want to find out the current height before the layout manager comes into play, you'd have to calculate that manually. Note that you could also call `layoutContainer(yourpanel)` on the layout manager before getting the current size - yet better `panel.doLayout()`.